# Changing logo color scheme

Tags: color, logo, copyright

I own a registered logo design. It is currently in black and white. Can I legally change the color scheme from black and white to other colors?

Comment: Registered where? Paying a design agency for ownership gives you title to the work they have completed. It is not the same as trademark ownership applied towards a business symbol. If you have registered the logo as a trademark, you can update this with a new submission. This is normal in the life of a brand. Shell over a short period: https://bit.ly/3x1SNnW  In terms of colour, it's SOP for a logo to be supplied in colour, black and white out so that it remains flexible for a wide range of applications. I generally provide an avatar now also for mobile / social https://bit.ly/2OZi4xW

Answer (score 2):

If you own the copyright to the artwork, you are free to do whatever you wish.